# Shouldn't all Public Domain DNS' resolve all addresses?

Tags: dns

I am developing web apps, and using different IP addresses to download new software as well as test against our hosted servers. What I have found is that I can resolve addresses in some cases against Google's PD DNS (8.8.8.8) but not others, specifically I had problems acquiring patches from Microsoft, who advised on their technical support to use 4.2.2.2 which worked (for me).

But then after using the recommended DNS from Microsoft, my hosted servers could not be resolved. I addressed this by using both DNS IP Addresses in primary and secondary settings. But shouldn't all PD DNS' be able to resolve all addresses ? If not why ? This could be a very broad question, so if you have references to explain this, please link them in your answer.)

Comment: Any changes in DNS in the last 48 hours?

Comment: No. I am using the same DNS and I was using the MS update site as a benchmark. I don't know if they muck about with their IP addresses. Assumed they won't since millions of ppl need to get patches of their crummy s/w

Comment: How do they differ? If you get *different* replies for `www.example.com` it may be due to round robin or geotagging. If one of them gives an `NXDOMAIN` have you tried walking doen the tree all the way from the root zone? For example, do they already disagree about `host -t NS example.com`? Have you checked the TTL?